# how to order through a mongoid association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid3

I want to order through a collections with values from an association.

Example:

> I got multible associations for a Post like:
>
> - Comments
> - Ratings
> - Attachements

How can i order the posts through this associations like:

> - order_by most_commented
> - order_by most_rated
> - order_by most_associations ....

Thank you.

Comment: I'd really love to know that, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i can answer this question ^^

With Mongoid [version 3.1](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/v3.1.0/CHANGELOG.md) the active record feature  "counter_cache" was aviable.
For example i got a post with referenced comments:

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :body, type: String

  has_many :comments                                                                                                                                                                             
end



class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :body, type: String

  belongs_to :post, counter_cache: true                                                                                                                                                                             
end
```

in this case every post instance got an comments_count field wich contains the number of comments are referenced in the post.

Now you can order your posts with the comments_count field.
Remember that this field is only available if at least one comment is present.
Or set the comments_count field explicit with an default value in your model.